# PHP sort multidimensional array using a specific key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which generated using PHP as below:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [user] => test 1 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location svvfefhsrdfd ) 
    [1] => Array ( [user] => test 2 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location fsdfdsv  ) 
    [2] => Array ( [user] => test 5 [esttime] => 8 mins [destination] => testing location scvvfe ) 
    [3] => Array ( [user] => test 3 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location sfds) 
    [4] => Array ( [user] => test 4 [esttime] => 8 mins [destination] => testing location gfsdarr ) 
    [5] => Array ( [user] => test 6 [esttime] => 10 mins [destination] => testing location dgfd ) 
)
```

the array have keys user,estimate time and destination and related values, i need to sort this array using esttime key value.

i tried many ways, but couldn't able to find a way.

anyone know how to sort this array using php, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use custom sorting `usort()` in this case, then just use `strtotime()` for that relative time:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    $time_a = strtotime($a['esttime']);
    $time_b = strtotime($b['esttime']);

    return $time_a - $time_b;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

[Sample Out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qe45BY)

Comment: I like this idea, that's a smart way to do it. I never would have even thought about a `strtotime()`...well obviously by my answer...

Comment: @Rasclatt that's a standard way, nothing special here.

Comment: @Rasclatt i maybe a little bit better handling the time, since we don't know maybe the OP might get an obscure case of `5mins 3hours` etc. might be better to handle it in its time context

Comment: Well, I learned something anyway (even if it is nothing special to other folks).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to generate a new array:

```
foreach($array as $row) {
        $new[str_replace(" ","_",$row['esttime'])][] = $row;
    }
```

**print_r($new) Should look like this after:**

```
Array (
        [5_mins][0] => Array ([user] => test 1 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location svvfefhsrdfd)
        [5_mins][1] => Array ( [user] => test 2 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location fsdfdsv)
        [5_mins][2] => Array ( [user] => test 3 [esttime] => 5 mins [destination] => testing location sfds)
        [8_mins][0] => Array ( [user] => test 5 [esttime] => 8 mins [destination] => testing location scvvfe )
        [8_mins][1] => Array ( [user] => test 4 [esttime] => 8 mins [destination] => testing location gfsdarr )
        [10_mins][0] => Array ( [user] => test 6 [esttime] => 10 mins [destination] => testing location dgfd )
      )
```

Comment: `usort` works on `O(nlogn)`, while this way works on `O(n)`. Faster algorithm.

Comment: @CertaiN this is like grouping rather than sorting. The OP's sample data is just an example, I don't think this can actually sort something more complex. for example try on this data `6 mins, 5 mins, 10 mins` (note that the OP's data is nearly sorted, so this works on that data).